# WinRM denied for remote powershell in C#, cryto needed?

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server, remote-access

I'am trying to create distribution groups for exchange with powershell from C# with this code :

```
    private void createDistributionGroup(string groupName, string DNOU)
    {
        System.Security.SecureString pass = new System.Security.SecureString("57R0NG_P455W0RD");
        PSCredential cred = new PSCredential(SA_username, pass);
        WSManConnectionInfo connection = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("http://myEXserver.mydomain.com/PowerShell/"), "https://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", cred);
        connection.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
        Runspace runspace = System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connection);
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        PSCommand command = new PSCommand();
        command.AddCommand("New-DistributionGroup");
        command.AddParameter("Name", groupName);
        ps.Commands = command;
        try
        {
            runspace.Open();
            ps.Runspace = runspace;
            ps.Invoke();
        }
        finally
        {
            runspace.Dispose();
            runspace = null;
            ps.Dispose();
            ps = null;
        }
    }
```

But when I execute this code, an winrm error append as :
connection forbiden, unencrypted trafic denied by the server...

How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use Kerberos Authentication?
If you do have to use Basic Authentication you have to use SSL. This sometimes is not configured correctly so you have do some tests.

Comment: I have tested with the kerberos authentication but it append an arror to

Answer (score 0):

With Basic auth you would (as TomG said) need to use SSL/HTTPS. You probably also need to set proxy authentication to Basic:

```
WSManConnectionInfo connection = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("**https**://myEXserver.mydomain.com/PowerShell/"), "https://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", cred);
connection.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
connection.ProxyAuthentication = AuthenticationMechanism.Basic;
```

When using Kerberos and HTTP, proxy access would be set to none:

```
WSManConnectionInfo connection = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("**http**://myEXserver.mydomain.com/PowerShell/"), "https://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", cred);
connection.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos;
connection.ProxyAccessType = ProxyAccessType.None;
```